# Get filename from the alphabetically last file in directory

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to get the last file's filename from a folder. I figured if I count the number of files in the folder and simply call upon the number associated with the file that it would solve the issue quickly, but apparently not. This is what I used for counting:

```
Dim path As String, counter As Integer

path = "D:\test\*.docm"

FileName = Dir(path)

Do While FileName <> ""
    count = counter + 1
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

msgbox counter
```

So if, for example, the last file counted is 5, how do I get its filename? Or is there a better way overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do 
    FileName = Dir()
    If Filename = "" then
        Exit Do
    Else
        RealFilename = Filename
    End If
Loop
```